# LINQ: Use FirstOrDefault to return an member or another

Tags: .net, linq

I'm having a misunderstanding problem with this use of Linq Query
I do have this Entity

```
class Content  
{          
    public string Type = "X";
    public string Name;  
    public int? Owner;  
}
```

and a List list
the list contains 2 members both equals by type except by the Name and Owner(one is null and the other is not).
So i tried do query to find the Content with an specific Owner, if none is found, return the other the query used below:

```
int? owner = 1;
  var result = (
     from c in list 
     where c.Type == "X" && c.Owner == owner 
     select c
     ).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "X" && c.Owner == (int?)null);
```

but the resulting member is returning null. What should be the correct statement for this query?

Comment: You shouldn't have to cast null to the int? type unless you are overloading the == operator.

Comment: If you always have only 2 members in the list, do you really need a LINQ query?

Comment: @channs I do not have always only 2 members, it will contains more members from different types, but I will aways have at least one of each type with null Owner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're applying *two* filters here. The `where` clause will only return values which have the given owner - and then the predicate in the `FirstOrDefault` clause will only consider values which have no owner.

I suggest you use:

```
var value = list.Where(c => c.Type == "X" && 
                            (c.Owner == null || c.Owner == owner))
                .OrderByDescending(c => c.Owner)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

Using `OrderByDescending` will put any value with a null owner *after* a value with a non-null owner, so when you take the first result it will get one with an owner if it's present.